# Detecting clicks on JFrame without any swing elements

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouse-listeners

I would like to detect when a user clicks on my JFrame. I have done a fair amount of research, but can only find information about clicking on Swing elements. I was hoping that you guys could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could help clarify what you mean by "detect clicks"? You want something to happen when the empty JFrame itself is clicked on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I can't fit this into a comment, I'll put this here:

```
frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {            
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Click!");
   }
});
```

Comment: You could also try adding the listener to the content pane